# How to switch an old .NET project to Linux?

Tags: asp.net, .net, linux, windows, webforms

I have a ASP.NET Framework 4.0 WebForms project running on several Windows servers. I wonder about the goals I should achieve to be able to host the project under Linux. Let us suppose I refactor the project and upgrade the version of the Framework to 4.5 or 4.6. If we assume that I do not have Windows-specific code in my project either because I never had such a code, or because I refactored it to not assume Windows-specific properties. My question is: what are the known mainstream .NET components that will break under Linux?

Comment: I believe WebForms cannot run under Linux. You will have to migrate to MVC to use .NET Core or Mono.

Comment: @Uno nope. WebForms is well supported by Mono. .NET Core only supports ASP.NET MVC Core, so still different from the classic ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks, I did not realise Mono implemented also WebForms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter how well you assert it on Windows, running the web app on Linux and Mono can reveal what does break.

This question therefore is too broad. I blogged about running ASP.NET 4.x web app on Mono,

Jexus Web Server and ASP.NET Cross Platform
I was invited by Mingzhi Yi to give a talk at Jiaodong Developer Conference 2015 on 12 Dec. It was about my opinions on Jexus and ASP.NET cross …

https://blog.lextudio.com/2015/12/jexus-web-server-and-asp-net-cross-platform/

You should note that .NET 4.6 might not be well supported on Mono, as it evolves slower than .NET.